# PHP var_dump counts excessive characters

Tags: php, var-dump

I have a string with 12 characters but PHP `var_dump` function counts 15.

PHP code:

```
var_dump('355 Rue Joly');
```

Result:

```
string(15) "355 Rue Joly"
```

Any explanation? Thanks.

Comment: What you posted only has 12 characters. https://3v4l.org/qler9 Probably `trim` can be used but would need to see real string to see where hidden characters are, and what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a character before the letter 3 and after the first `'` which you can't see. You should remove that.

When you paste it in another editor (visual studio code for example it should show a "?" meaning it doesn't know what character there actually is.)

Comment: but how to remove it if I cannot see it?

Comment: @bizobizo You use a editor which shows these caracters (like visual studio code)


EDIT: You can also paste this peice of code in ur URL bar and then press backspace once after the 3, this should look like its the same but has removed that character

Comment: @bizobizo if you select something with your mouse (e.g. "Rue", from right to left) and then do Shift+Left on your keyboard repetitively, you will notice the additional character before `3`.

Comment: @bizobizo or for a simple string like this, you can delete it (with the quotes) and re-type it